# python serial port communication

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, serial-port, microcontroller

Here is my code for serial port communication

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style


import serial
MCU = serial.Serial('COM35', 115200, timeout=.1)


import time
time.sleep(1) #give the connection a second to settle

while True:
     data = MCU.readline()
print(str(data))
```

but i'm getting in the **output** as

`b'\x0b\x16 )6\x06\x07\x08X\x02\x16,'`     (it's Hex+Ascii value)

and this is my **input data**

`uint8_t myBuf[]={11,22,32,41,54,6,7,8,88,2,22,44};`

any one know what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What format do you want your output in? As you suggest, what you have is the correct data but in byte format. For example you could get it as a list of python ints as follows (Python 3):

```
>>> list(data)
[11, 22, 32, 41, 54, 6, 7, 8, 88, 2, 22, 44]
```

The [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module may also be useful for you in decoding byte data.

(I can't leave a comment, sorry.)

Answer (score 1):

When you wrote str(data) you requested python to tranlsate the binary data to a readable string (In a readable fromat).

Since there is no readable representation to most of the bytes python just translates them into their hex representation (as a string).

If you want to print them as a list just: list(data).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be good idea to try to decode it?

just as idea

```
while ser.isOpen():
    for s in ser.read():
        s = ser.readline().decode('utf-8') #reading data from the port with decoding from UTF-8
        com = str(s).replace('\n','') #cutting out second pass to the new line
        print(s)
```